# python&linux pip always try to use python2.7 instead of 3.4

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-venv

Ask: I can't install or upgrade any lib for python 3.4 because pip, pip3, pip3.4 not working or connected to python2.7.

1. I tried to set alias python=python3 and use just pip:

   sudo pip install selenium

   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
2. I tried pip3:

   sudo pip3 install selenium

   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
3. I tried pip3.4:

   sudo pip3.4 install selenium

   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
4. I tried to create venv for python3.4:

   volodka@interceptor:/usr/bin$ sudo virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 python3env
   Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.4
   Using base prefix '/usr'
   New python executable in python3env/bin/python3.4
   Also creating executable in python3env/bin/python
   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

   volodka@interceptor:/usr/bin/python3env/bin$ . activate

   (python3env)volodka@interceptor:/usr/bin/python3env/bin$ sudo pip install selenium
       Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Pip3, pip3.4 in virtualenv also try to install lib for python2.7. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your system is broken (unsurprisingly, taking into account some of things you did). Though things in the answers and in your comments will break that even more.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you should take is to install pip for `Python 3.4`.

You do this in the following way:

```
$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python3.4 get-pip.py
```

You then install things for Python 3.4 with pip3.4, and you install things with Python 2-7 with pip-2.7.

Check `/usr/bin` to see which pip versions you have there.

Comment: `volodka@interceptor:~/Downloads$ sudo python3.4 get-pip.py 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
volodka@interceptor:~/Downloads$ pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

And I have no pips in /usr/bin:


`volodka@interceptor:~/Downloads$ whereis pip

pip: /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.4 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz`

Comment: try `pip3.4 install selenium`

Comment: I did
`volodka@interceptor:~/Downloads$ sudo pip3.4 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selenium in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
Should I move python3.4 to /usr/bin?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not the best solution. Having the same issue on Fedora 22, I managed to install python3 packages using pip this way:`sudo pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages" package_name`